# Show that the matrix $I+A$ is invertible when $A$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If  $A$ is a nilpotent matrix, then how to show that the matrix $I+A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

$(I + A)(\sum_0^n (-A)^j) = \sum_0^n (-A)^j + A\sum_0^n (-A)^j$
$ = \sum_0^n (-A)^j - (-A)\sum_0^n (-A)^j = \sum_0^n (-A)^j - \sum_0^n (-A)^{j + 1}$
$= \sum_0^n (-A)^j - \sum_1^{n + 1} (-A)^j = I + \sum_1^n (-A)^j - \sum_1^n (-A)^j  - (-A)^{n + 1}$
$= I - (-A)^{n + 1}, \tag{1}$

which holds for any positive integer $n$.  If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^m = 0$ for some positive integer m.  Thus, by (1),

$(I + A)(\sum_0^m (-A)^j) = I - (-A)^{m + 1} = I, \tag{2}$

showing the inverse of $I + A$ is in fact $\sum_0^m (-A)^j$.  And that's how it is shown.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly different approach:

If $A$ is nilpotent, we have $A^n = 0$.

If $\det (I+A) = 0$, we have $(I+A) v = 0$ for some $v \neq 0$, that is
$Av = -v$. Then $A^n v = (-1)^nv$, which contradicts $A^n = 0$.

Comment: There should be some $-1$s in there.

Comment: @Slade: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let us put $B=-A$

Compute: $$(I- B)(I+B+\cdots B^n)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is nilpotent, then $0$ is the only possible eigenvalue of $A$ (since each eigenvalue must satisfy $\lambda^k=0$ if $A^k=0$). In particular $-1$ is not an eigenvalue, i.e., $A+I$ is injective, hence invertible.